# Minimum phase All-pass

Tags: allpass, minimum-phase

Why is it that reflecting any poles or zeros of a rational function gives a minimum phase system? And why is doing that make a unique minimum phase system?

I understand the all-pass function absorbs the poles or zeros when you reflect it, not sure if that has something to do with it. Also, wouldn't reflecting any poles or zeros potentially cause some poles and zeros that were before in the stability region to be out of it?

Answer (score 2):

An LTI system is said to be [minimum-phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase) if the system and its inverse system are causal and stable. That's implying that all poles and zeros must be strictly inside the unit circle.

An [all-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter)'s zero-pole pairs are reflections of each other across the unit circle so that an all-pass filter absorbs the poles or zeros. For a stable all-pass filter, its zeros are outside the unit circle and its poles are inside the unit circles.

A causal and stable mixed-phase system has all poles inside the unit circle and zeros which could be inside or outside the unit circle. <del>Therefore, reflecting zeros outside the unit circle by cascading an all-pass system makes all zeros inside the unit circle, which means you get a minimum-phase system.</del> (As Dan pointed out in the comment, cascading an all pass with a mixed-phase system is incorrect. Extracting an all pass from the mixed phase results in a minimum phase, or in the contrary cascading an all pass with a minimum phase results in a mixed-phase system.)

Once you get a minimum-phase system, the only thing you can do to prevent changing its magnitude response is to cascade an all-pass system. That brings additional zeros outside the unit circle and the system is no longer minimum-phase. Therefore minimum-phase system with a specific magnitude response is unique.

Comment: a pure delay is also an all-pass filter.  it's not an IIR APF.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes i've edited the answer

Comment: So lets say I have a rational function H, if I just reflect all the poles and zeros of that H, that gives me a minimum phase system? What if H has poles and zeroes in the unit circle? Or maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @d4898ty You have a rational function H, with all poles and some of zeros inside the unit circle and other zeros outside the unit circle. Reflect all the zeros outside the unit circle and you get a minimum-phase system. If H already has all the poles and zeros inside the unit circle, it is a minimum-phase system.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson hi robert i still have a question. For a minimum-phase system, adding any pure delay it's still a minimum-phase system. Then how can I say the minimum-phase system is unique corresponding to the given spectral magnitude?

Comment: i would not agree to the claim that adding a pure delay to a minimum-phase system results in a minimum-phase system.  a pure delay is in the category of FIR filters.  FIR filters have poles **only** at the origin ($z=0$) but zeros at other places.  i don't think the zeros of the pure delay will be inside the unit circle.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thanks. From a rational standpoint, I don’t think a pure delay is minimum phased as well, but I can’t see any zero of it, are they at $z=\infty$? I’m also confused about MATLAB’s ‘isminphase’ function, which claims all FIR filters to be minimum-phase system.

Comment: yes they are equivalently at $\infty$ because $H(z)=z^{-D}$ has $D$ poles at $z=0$  you can think of it as a cascade of $D$ APF filters with poles very close to zero and finite zeros and then apply the limit as the poles approach zero, their reflected zeros go to $\infty$.

Comment: i wonder if a Hilbert transformer can legitimately be called an APF?  it doesn't pass DC, but it passes every other frequency component.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks. And I think a Hilbert transformer is not “all” pass , legitimately, cause DC does matter sometimes.

Comment: @ZRHan I find the 3rd paragraph confusing as written as it sounds like you are saying cascading a mixed phase system with an all-pass will result in a minimum phase system. I believe you mean that if we have a minimum phase system, and cascade that with an all-pass, the result will be a mixed phase system.   (cascading an all-pass means putting an all-pass in series which does not reflect zeros)

Comment: @DanBoschen Yes, you are right. I meant not cascading, but extracting an all-pass from the mixed-phase system and geting a minimum-phase system, which in another word means cascading a minimum-phase with an all-pass results in a mixed-phase.